# Need help sending custom info to php global vars

Tags: php, apache, browser, xss

Is is possible to send custom information to `$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR];` or `$_SERVER[HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR];` ?
I want to make these vars output my custom text. I thought about editing headers sent by browser or sending it with php script/curl program. But I don't know how. Please tell me if it is possible and how.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` as that's the IP address of the TCP connection. The only way to change that is to actually connect from a different real IP address.

You can send whatever `X-FORWARDED-FOR` header you want in the HTTP request. All that header is used for is to hint that the connecting IP is proxying a request for some other client. It's not relied upon for anything important.

Comment: And please, can you give me example of sending x-forwarded-for with php ?

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Forwarded-For: 55.55.55.55'));`